# Hex circle packing vs square circle packing in games

Tags: language-agnostic, packing

Why do games such as "Frozen Bubbles" use hexadecimal circle packing? Is that somehow better than square packing?

Answer (score 3):

Well, they are bubbles and not cubes.  It turns out *hexagonal* (not hexadecimal) packing is a more efficient use of space than square packing, and for games like "Frozen Bubbles" it offers (in my opinion) more interesting gameplay because of the angles.